# R {sp} spatial subset: keep so many polygons as number of overlapping points

Tags: r, spatial-analyst, point-in-polygon, subset

I have a set of overlapping **spatial points** and **spatial polygons**. I need to subset the polygons by overlapping points, but, **if my polygon contains 2 points, I need to keep polygon twice**, etc.

To keep each polygon only once, I can simply use `sp::over` in following statement:

```
# keep polygons that contains points
outFc<- polygons[!is.na(sp::over(polygons, 
                                  sp::geometry(points))),]
```

How to keep multiple polygons, if multiple points overlaps it?

[image]

---

My example:

```
library(sp)
library(rgeos)

# Create points and convert them to spatialPointsDataFrame
pts = data.frame(cbind(c(-0.3, -0.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.1), 
                       c(-0.3, -0.2, 1.9, 0.8, 0.4)))

pointsDF = SpatialPointsDataFrame(pts, pts)
pointsDF@data$IDs = paste0("pts", 1:nrow(pointsDF@data))


# Create multiple polygons and merge them into one file
p1 = readWKT("POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 1, 0 0))", id = "stand1")
p2 = readWKT("POLYGON((0 1, 1 1, 1 2, 0 2, 0 1))", id = "stand2")  # 0.5 1,0 2,1 2,0.5 1
p3 = readWKT("POLYGON((0 -2, -1 -2, -1 -1, 0 -1, 0 -2))", id= "stand3")   # 0.5 0.5,0 1.5,1 1.5,0.5 0.5

polys <- rbind(p1,p2,p3, makeUniqueIDs = TRUE)

# windows()
plot(polys)
plot(pointsDF, add = T, col = "red")


# keep polygons that contains points
#-----------------------------------------------------------
# ??? How to change this to keep one polygon for each point, i.e. multiply the polygons???
# ----------------------------------------------------------
outPoly <- polys[!is.na(sp::over(polys, 
                                  sp::geometry(pointsDF))),]
```

The number of selected polygons is 2, but should be 3. It is **ok that my polygons would overlap**.

I though that I can:

1. create new feature class for each row in a points
2. subset the polygons with my single point
3. if not emply, add this polygon to final `outPoly`

something like this (not working yet!):

```
# Subset each polygon once

outPolyLs <- SpatialPolygons(list())

    for (i in 1:nrow(pointsDF)) {
      row <- pointsDF[i,]
      print(row)
      outPolyLs[[i]]<-polys[!is.na(sp::over(polys, 
                            sp::geometry(row))),]
      # check if contains any feature, if yes, add it to final output polygons 
    }
```

But I wonder if it is a correct approach, or there is an easier way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First:

```
> library(raster) # makes sp things print nicer
```

If you do your `over` the other way round:

```
> over(sp::geometry(pointsDF), polys)
 1  2  3  4  5 
NA NA  2  1  1
```

the result is a vector of the index in `polys` for each point with `NA` for points outside. Remove the `NA` values:

```
> pindex = over(sp::geometry(pointsDF), polys)
> pindex = pindex[!is.na(pindex)]
> pindex
3 4 5 
2 1 1
```

And that is a vector of elements of `polys` we want to select. Annoyingly simple vector selection of `SpatialPolygons` doesn't let you replicate:

```
> polys[c(1,1)]
Error in polys[c(1, 1)] : 
  SpatialPolygons selection: can't find plot order if polygons are replicated
>
```

but one way round this to make a spatial data frame and index that:

```
> polysDF = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(
    polys,
    data.frame(
       i=1:length(polys)),
       match.ID=FALSE)[pindex,]
```

giving

```
> polysDF
class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 3 
extent      : 0, 1, 0, 2  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : NA 
variables   : 1
names       : i 
min values  : 1 
max values  : 2 
>
```

the source polygon index is kept:

```
> polysDF$i
[1] 2 1 1
```

Comment: thank you @spacedman, seems to work great! this is a nice workaround!

Comment: Just to complete, if using `SpatialPolygonDataFrame` objects, first convert them to geometry objects, i.e. `SpatialPoints` or `SpatialPolygons`. Use `pindex = over(sp::geometry(pointsDF.t), sp::geometry(polys))`